# Passing a dict of tensors to a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to preprocess the infamous Titanic data (from Kaggle) by following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) tutorial.
Everything was okay until I get to run the *titanic_processing* Model on the data (*titanic_features*) and I get this error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

In the tutorial it is mentioned that one should transform the data into a dict of tensors, but:

1. I don't see how the code (see HERE1 tag in my code below) makes a dict of tensors (there is no *tf.convert_to_tensor* for example)
2. I don't understand why one should retransform all the data as the previous code was suppose to do just that (when one create *preprocessed_inputs* etc.)

Here is my code, but you can also execute it on Google Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16QW3DVkk_vB1EM-Eg7GZ01mWNRU-xZD5?usp=sharing).

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing


url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aymeric75/IA/master/train.csv"
titanic = pd.read_csv(url)


titanic_features = titanic.copy()
titanic_labels = titanic_features.pop('Survived')


inputs = {}

for name, column in titanic_features.items():
    dtype = column.dtype
    if dtype == object:
        dtype = tf.string
    else:
        dtype = tf.float32
    inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)

numeric_inputs = {name:input for name,input in inputs.items()
                  if input.dtype==tf.float32}

x = layers.Concatenate()(list(numeric_inputs.values()))
norm = preprocessing.Normalization()
norm.adapt(np.array(titanic[numeric_inputs.keys()]))

all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)
preprocessed_inputs = [all_numeric_inputs]


for name, input in inputs.items():
    if input.dtype == tf.float32:
        continue
    
    lookup = preprocessing.StringLookup(vocabulary=np.unique(titanic_features[name].dropna()))
    one_hot = preprocessing.CategoryEncoding(max_tokens=lookup.vocab_size())

    x = lookup(input)
    x = one_hot(x)
    preprocessed_inputs.append(x)


preprocessed_inputs_cat = layers.Concatenate()(preprocessed_inputs)
titanic_preprocessing = tf.keras.Model(inputs, preprocessed_inputs_cat)

titanic_features_dict = {}

# This model just contains the input preprocessing. You can run it to see what it does to your data.
# Keras models don't automatically convert Pandas DataFrames because
# it's not clear if it should be converted to one tensor or to a dictionary of tensors. So convert it to a dictionary of tensors:
# HERE1

titanic_features_dict = {name: np.array(value) 
                         for name, value in titanic_features.items()}

features_dict = {name:values[:1] for name, values in titanic_features_dict.items()}

titanic_preprocessing(features_dict)
```

Thanks a lot for you support!

Aymeric

**[UPDATE]** if you can answer question 2 ("I don't understand why one should retransform all the data as the previous code was suppose to do just that (when one create *preprocessed_inputs* etc.") then I will validate your answer, because I think I need to reformat the input indeed (but I don't see what it the point of doing all the code before...)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem is caused by the fact that your feature "Cabin" contains some `nan` (Not a Number) values. Tensorflow is fine with `nan` in floating point and integer data types, but not for strings.

You can replace all those nan values with an empty strings in your pandas dataframe :

```
titanic_features["Cabin"] = titanic_features["Cabin"].fillna("")
```

---

The previous code simply declares a preprocessing function as a keras model. You don't actually preprocess any data until your call to the `titanic_preprocessing` model.